# Loop within my single.php WordPress blog only return for one post

Tags: php, loops, return, sidebar

hi i has a wordpress blog i put this code below within single.php page in side bar
the code is the same code in the hompage side bar >
this code is correctly work in hompage sidebar and return to all posts
but in the single.php sidebar only return to one post.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<div class="new-posts-form">
<div class="new-posts-img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,80)); ?></a></div>
<div class="new-posts-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
 <div class="new-post-description"><?php content('11'); ?></div>
 <div class="new-post-add-date-time"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/tb_clock.png" /><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> : <?php the_category(', ') ?></div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The `single` in `single.php` should give you a clue why … :)

Answer (score 1):

I think on single.php page you should use this

for reference please check
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

i am trying to solve your problem hope this help.

thanks
anand